# Keep div centered but smaller than window

Tags: html, css, resize

Let's say i have a div with text applied by the server with varying text height.

```
<div id="info_box">
   Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

I want to float it in the middle of the window,
and it should not grow longer then the window's size,
instead add scrollbars.

I can gain this so far by adding the styles

```
position: fixed;
top: 15px;
bottom: 15px;
overflow: auto;
```

to the div.

( <strike>http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/363/</strike> http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/370/ )

But my problem is, if the text is shorter then my window's height, my `div` still is 'fullscreen'.
If the text is shorter it should be sized fitting (something like `height: auto;`, and positioned to the center.

How to do that with CSS?

**Edit**: Cleaned Up Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/370/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution.  The `#info-box` is centered in the middle using a left negative margin and translateY() transform.  The former is used because the width is explicitly set (i.e., 350px).  The latter had to be used because the height of the box is dynamic.  Older browsers do not support transforms and you may need to use a polyfill.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxQ2V/.

**Edit:** Cleanup: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/371/

```
#info_box {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left:-200px; 
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Cleanup here too, http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/371/ sorry for my messy code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Not best but one solution is this : >> [click here[1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/367/)]

css

---

```
    html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    background: #D0CDC5 url("http://i.imgur.com/5KpR9.jpg") center top repeat;
    background-repeat-x: repeat;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;
    background-attachment: initial;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0%;
    background-origin: initial;
    background-clip: initial;
    background-color: #D0CDC5;
    color: #333;
    height:100%;
}

html {
    height:100%;
}

#page_container {
    height:100%;
}

#page_wrapper {
}

#info_box {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 350px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 15px;
}

#info_box p {
    background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.5);
    border: rgba(34,34,34,0.9) 1px solid;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #76d4ff;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you did change

Comment: background-color and border is moved to info_box_p from info_box

Comment: Oh, you also changed `position: fixed` to `position: absolute`.

Comment: oh yeahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh you can use any of them in your case

Comment: Cleaned up my fiddle, so your changes should look like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ax82j/369/ which is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58125/discussion-between-luckydonald-and-eirenaios).

Answer (score 1):

A more simple approach to this without using webkits. You can customize background-color, width and height according to your need, it will automatically set it up into center no matter what width and height you set. You can remove height or set it to auto if you want it to be the maximum of windows height but not more than that.

```
#infobox {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
width:20em; 
height:20em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border:solid 1px #000000;
margin: auto;
overflow:auto;
}
```

If you dont want to middle it vertically then add margin-top:0px to the code as following

```
#infobox {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
width:20em; 
height:20em;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
border:solid 1px #000000;
margin: auto;
margin-top:0px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: you are using the second code which means its not vertically middle. If you want to middle it vertically too then use the first code block in my answer. this link is for second code block